# Graph visualization of existing .NET code

Tags: .net, dependencies, reverse-engineering, diagram, dependency-management

I've seen that VS 2010 Ultimate can generate model graph from existing code. But VS 2010 Ultimate version costs 11K US$, way too much for my budget. Is there any good alternative to do graph visualization of .NET code?

Comment: Have you considered applying for a Bizspark membership, allowing you to access all Microsoft products for free ? https://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NDepend comes with a [dependency graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#DependenciesView) coupled with a dependency matrix. You can try NDepend straight on your code thanks to a **Free Trial Edition**. Read more about this feature in this article [Exploring Existing Code Architecture in Visual Studio](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx). Any kind of graph is supported including:

- Dependency Graph
- Call Graph
- Class Inheritance Graph
- Coupling Graph
- Path Graph
- All Paths Graph
- Cycle Graph
- Large Graph visualized with Dependency Structure Matrix

Here are screenshots for illustration:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about the [graph add-in](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Graph&referringTitle=Home) for .Net Reflector?

Answer (score 0):

**Reflector** has addins which can already show something like this: http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/.

And I believe **NDepend** also has a dependency graph: http://www.ndepend.com/Screenshots.aspx.